# CSS3 Hexagon with dotted border

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I could achieve a hexagon with solid border as below:

```css
.hex {
  margin-top: 70px;
  width: 208px;
  height: 120px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
.hex:before,
.hex:after {
  content: "";
  border-left: 104px solid transparent;
  border-right: 104px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
}
.hex:before {
  top: -59px;
  border-bottom: 60px solid red;
}
.hex:after {
  bottom: -59px;
  border-top: 60px solid red;
}
.hex.inner {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  -webkit-transform: scale(.98, .98);
  -moz-transform: scale(.98, .98);
  transform: scale(.98, .98);
  z-index: 1;
}
.hex.inner:before {
  border-bottom: 60px solid lightgreen;
}
.hex.inner:after {
  border-top: 60px solid lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="hex">
  <div class="hex inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I would like to create a **hexagon with a dotted border** as seen in the image below:

[image: Hexagon with a dotted border]

Comment: Just use boder : 1px dashed or dotted....

Comment: this could be easily obtained with SVG. Do you need to use html elements?

Comment: @fcalderan : I'm open to SVG or HTML5 Canvas

Comment: @Aeldred : I'm unable to achieve that, please help with the above code.

Comment: @Pugazh I make it using css check it.

Comment: @Pugazh see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Html Code:

```
<div class="hexagon"><span></span></div>
```

Css code :

```
  .hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px; 
  height: 173.21px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 86.60px 0;
   border-left: 3px dotted #f00;;
  border-right:3px dotted #f00;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 212.13px;
  height: 212.13px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: inherit;
  left: 40.9340px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.hexagon:before {
  top: -106.0660px;
  border-top: 3px dotted #f00;
  border-right:3px dotted #f00;
}

.hexagon:after {
  bottom: -106.0660px;
  border-bottom: 3px dotted #f00;
  border-left: 3px dotted #f00;
}

/*cover up extra shadows*/
.hexagon span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top:1.7320508075688772px;
  left: 0;
  width:294px;
  height:169.7410px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: inherit;
}
```

output :

[image]

Apply color as you nedd.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an approach with an [inline svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction) using:

- the [polygon element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon) for the hexagon shape
- [stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) for the dotted border (control of the size and space between dots)
- [stroke-linecap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-linecap) for the dotted border

```css
svg{width:30%;margin:0 auto;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <polygon fill="#92D050" 
           stroke="red"
           stroke-width="1"
           stroke-linecap="round"
           stroke-dasharray="0.5,3"
           points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 6):

You are unable to create a dotted border using the method given in question because there the shape itself is created using borders. The `border-top` and `border-bottom` that produce the hexagon. When you set the `dotted` border-style to it, all you'd get is very large dots that wouldn't be like the expected output. While you can use other CSS methods to create the required shape + border (like described in other answers), it is better to use SVG for such complex shapes because it is easy.

You can do this easily with SVG using a single `path` element. The `path` is simple to create once you have a good understanding of the commands that are used in creating it.

Below is an explanation:

- `M5,30` - This command **M**oves the imaginary pen to the point represented by (5,30).
- `L50,0` - This draws a **L**ine from the previous point (5,30) to the point (50,0).
- `95,30 95,70 50,100 5,70` - These are same as the previous commands and draw lines to the respective points. The command (`L`) itself need not be repeated as it is the same.

The dotted border is achieved by setting the correct values for the `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-linecap` properties (as mentioned in web-tiki's answer).

```css
svg {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
path {
  fill: green;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-dasharray: 0.1, 3;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 100 100'>
  <path d='M5,30 L50,0 95,30 95,70 50,100 5,70z' />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

Love the SVG solutions (@web-tiki and @Harry) but here's an CSS solution using 3 rectangles:

```css
.main{
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.a, .b, .c{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 120px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: green;
  border-left: 2px dotted red;
  border-right: 2px dotted red;
}

.a{
  z-index: 1;
}

.b{
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

.c{
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ma45kekk/)

---

A solution using only one HTML element:

```css
body{
  padding: 50px;
}

.hex, .hex:before, .hex:after{
  width: 120px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: green;
  border-left: 2px dotted red;
  border-right: 2px dotted red;
}

.hex:before, .hex:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.hex{
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.hex:before{
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

.hex:after{
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="hex"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ma45kekk/2/)